# Perl : adding two durations respecting format hh:mm:ss,sss (using DateTime)

Tags: perl, datetime, time, duration

I want to add two durations using [`DateTime::Format::Duration`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime::Format::Duration).

Here's my code

```
my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
   pattern => '%H:%M:%S,%3N'
);

my $dur1 = $format->format_duration('01:59:58,923');
my $dur2 = $format->format_duration('05:01:02,456');

my $total = $dur1->add_duration( $dur2 );
print "\nDuration : " . $total;
```

When I execute, I get the error

```
Can't call method "deltas" without a package or object reference at D:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/DateTime/Format/Duration.pm line 131.
```

The result I expect should be in the format : `hh:mm:ss,sss`. (n.b. the total of the two durations never exceeds 24 hours)

**EDIT 1**

```
my $dur1 = $format->parse_duration('01:59:58,923');
my $dur2 = $format->parse_duration('05:01:02,456');
my $total1 = $dur1->add_duration( $dur2 );
my $total2 = $dur1 + $dur2;       
print "\nTotal Duration 1: " . $format->parse_duration($total1);
print "\nTotal Duration 2: " . $format->parse_duration($total2);
```

Here's the output I get :

> Total Duration 1: DateTime::Duration=HASH(0x2be8564)
>   Total Duration 2: DateTime::Duration=HASH(0x2be6d74)

**EDIT 2 :**

Here's my new code :

```
my $dur1 = $format->parse_duration('01:59:51,923');
my $dur2 = $format->parse_duration('05:21:02,456');

my $total = $dur1->add_duration( $dur2 );

my ($h, $m, $s, $ns) = $total->in_units(qw( hours minutes seconds ));
my $ns = ( $total )->nanoseconds; # delta_ms loses these.
if ( $ns >= 1000 ) {
                        $ns = $ns - 1000;
                        $s = $s + 1;
            }

# print $ns ."\n\n";
my $final =  sprintf '%d:%02d:%02d,%03.0f', $h, $m, $s, $ns;

print $final;
```

Apparently, it does the job. I would like to know what you think about it.

**EDIT 3**

After executing this code for instance :

```
my $dur1 = $format->parse_duration('00:00:50,339');
my $dur2 = $format->parse_duration('00:00:58,686');

my $total = $dur1->add_duration( $dur2 );

my ($h, $m, $s) = $total->in_units(qw( hours minutes seconds ));
my $ns = ( $total )->nanoseconds;
if ( $ns >= 1000 ) {
                        $ns = $ns - 1000;
                        $s = $s + 1;
            }

# 00:00:02,339  00:00:00,686

my $duration =  sprintf '%d:%02d:%02d,%03.0f', $h, $m, $s, $ns;

print "\nDuration : " . $duration;
```

Here's the output : `Duration : 0:00:109,025`. This seems obvious because there's no "inner" conversion made by `DateTime::Duration->add_duration`.

Comment: The `format_duration` function takes a `DateTime::Duration` object as argument, but you gave a string `'01:59:58,923'`

Comment: How do I convert it to a `DateTime::Duration` object please ?

Comment: You are using `format_duration` to *parse* a string. It is obvious, and the documentation explains clearly, that you should use `parse_duration` to do that. Note also that you are adding 923 and 456 *nanoseconds*, which is 1.379 *microseconds*, or 0.000001379 seconds. If you use the same pattern `%3N` to format that, you will always get `.000`

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for your reply. I've just edited my post to show the error I'm getting. Sorry, I'm new to Perl...

Comment: @Borodin : Could you please take a look at my **EDIT 2** ?

Answer (score 2):

There are ***two*** different objects you're working with here:

- [DateTime::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration) objects
- [DateTime::Format::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration) objects.

What you need to do is create a `DateTime::Duration` with your two durations, then use a `DateTime::Format::Duration` object to create a format for them to use.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables

use feature qw(say);

use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

#
# First Create the Durations
#
my $dur1 = DateTime::Duration->new(
    hours       => 1,
    minutes     => 59,
    seconds     => 58,
    nanoseconds => 923,
);

my $dur2 = DateTime::Duration->new(
    hours       => 5,
    minutes     => 59,
    seconds     => 02,
    nanoseconds => 923,
);

#
# Add the two durations together.
# This creates a new DateTime::Duration object
#
my $total = $dur1->add($dur2);

#
# Great. It all works. Let's create a format, so we can print it out
#
my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern => '%H:%M:%S,%3N',
    normalize => 1,             # Normalize (i.e. minutes can't be more than 59)
);

#
# Use 'format_duration` to create a string representation of the duration
#
say "Duration: " . $format->format_duration($total);
```

It can sometimes be confusing to keep track of all the various object types that are used, but it's important to understand what a method uses and returns. I find it important to read and understand the Synopsis examples to really understand what's going on. This was from the [DateTime::Format::Duration](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration) synopsis:

```
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

$d = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
        pattern => '%Y years, %m months, %e days, '.
                        '%H hours, %M minutes, %S seconds'
);

print $d->format_duration(
        DateTime::Duration->new(
                years   => 3,
                months  => 5,
                days    => 1,
                hours   => 6,
                minutes => 15,
                seconds => 45,
                nanoseconds => 12000
        )
);
```

I am creating a format object type, then use the `format_duration` method to print it out, but the `format_duration` method takes a `DateTime::Duration` object! Look in the POD under that `format_duration` method, and it says:

> format_duration( $datetime_duration_object )

Yeah, that's helpful. What's `$datetime_duration_object` suppose to be? The documentation could use a bit of work. Fortunately, the synopsis is clear.